# Using the boxCox on Multilinear Regression

Tags: r, statistics

I am using multilinear regression on a data set. I've checked and almost none of the needed assumptions are met. I am trying to use boxCox to know what transformations to do, but I can't get it to work either.

I named my data frame df1, and it has a responsive variable of Energy and predictor variables of Date, Day, and MinTemp. Date is binary a binary factor (1 for 2010 or 0 for 2009), Day is a factor, and MinTemp is numerical. There are negative values in MinTemp.

This is my code for boxCox:

```
bc_snow = boxCox(df1$Energy ~ df1$Date + df1$Day + df1$MinTemp, family = "bcnPower")
```

It outputs this for me, which for some reason looks wrong to me.

[image]

I also am trying to pull my lambda, which I've done before, and the code isnt working.

```
bc_snow$x[which.max(bc$y)] 

Error in bc$y : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

What am I doing wrong? I've done boxCox before but haven't run into this problem.

I've tried changing the family in the boxCox, but that hasn't helped me either.

Comment: What is `bc`? You are not defining it in the code you showed.

Comment: bc_snow is the name of the boxcox I am making. I changed my second code to have 'bc_snow$y` instead now

Comment: `bc_snow` and `bc` are visibly not the same thing. Try `bc_snow$x[which.max(bc_snow$y)] `